# C++: While loop condition executes continuously, loop body never executes

Tags: c++, while-loop, infinite-loop

What is wrong with this code? Why does the loop condition execute repeatedly while the loop body never does? It is driving me insane! I can't see the problem:

```
bool test() { std::cout << "condition!" << std::endl; return true; }

while(test());
{
   std::cout << "This message never appears!!!" << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
condition!
condition!
condition!
...forever
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course I am blind, and the reason is the errant semicolon after the "while"! The compiler thinks there is no loop body, and just executes "nothing" repeatedly. What I read as the loop body, the compiler just thinks is an un-named/anonymous scope, AFTER the loop, so it never gets executed.